# C program exits on executing execlp function

Tags: c

I know that execlp replaces the current process.I am trying to run

```
execlp("mpg123", "mpg123", "-q", "1.mp3", 0);
```

Is there any way i can keep the program running while execlp executes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) a new process, and do the `exec` call in the child process:

```
pid_t child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == -1)
    perror("fork");
else if (child_pid == 0)
{
    /* In child process, call `exec*` */
}
else
{
    /* In parent process, continue doing... things... */
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain, that the `exec` family of function effectively replaces the process it is called from. It's in the man pages.